# Unable to get md5 hash

Tags: linux, ssl, openssl, md5

I am unable to get the md5 hash using OpenSSL. I am using the following command for build :

```
gcc -Wall test_3.c -o test_3 -lcrypto -lssl
```

but getting the the following link errors :

```
undefined reference to `MD5Init'
undefined reference to `MD5Update'
undefined reference to `MD5Final'
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
```

The program is present below :

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<string.h>
#include <openssl/hmac.h>
#include <openssl/md5.h>

int main()
{
  char    digest[17];
  char input[] = "asdfljiahfbqhebfjcnajclgfeliuaef";
  int length = strlen(input);

  MD5_CTX md5;

  MD5Init(&md5);
  MD5Update(&md5,input, length);
  MD5Final(digest,&md5);
  printf("digest  is %s \n",digest);

  return 0;
}
```

Please let me know if you know the problem.Please help me out

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You made some mistakes, I've corrected them. Also I've added hexadecimal output of the hash. Otherwise it will break your terminal.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <openssl/hmac.h>
#include <openssl/md5.h>

int main()
{
    // use unsigned char
    unsigned char    digest[16];
    char *input = "hek2mgl";
    int length = strlen(input);
    int i=0;

    // don't miss the underscore after MD5
    MD5_CTX md5;    
    MD5_Init(&md5);

    while (length > 0) {
        if (length > 512) {
            MD5_Update(&md5, input, 512);
        } else {
            MD5_Update(&md5, input, length);
        }
        length -= 512;
        input += 512;
    }

    MD5_Final(digest, &md5);
    printf("digest is: ");
    for(i = 0; i < 16; i++) {
        printf("%02x", digest[i]);
    }
    printf("\n");
    return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
digest is: 1ff8a3b2958ee3340ed88a2b980a8099
```

Comment: Believe it or not, a grep of the mis-spelled function shows OpenSSL provides them as demo code in `<openssl dir>/demos/engines/rsaref/rsaref.c`.

Answer (score 3):

In addition to hek2mgl's answer, the OpenSSL wiki offers the following example at [EVP Message Digests](http://wiki.openssl.org/index.php/EVP_Message_Digests).

The `EVP_*` interfaces are recommended, especially for those who are not familiar with some of OpenSSL's features and quirks (which can be a good thing). Instead of `EVP_sha256()`, just use `EVP_md5()`.

```
void digest_message(unsigned char *message, unsigned char **digest, unsigned int *digest_len)
{
    EVP_MD_CTX *mdctx;

    if((mdctx = EVP_MD_CTX_create()) == NULL)
        handleErrors();

    if(1 != EVP_DigestInit_ex(mdctx, EVP_sha256(), NULL))
        handleErrors();

    if(1 != EVP_DigestUpdate(mdctx, message, strlen(message)))
        handleErrors();

    if((*digest = (unsigned char *)OPENSSL_malloc(EVP_MD_size(EVP_sha256()))) == NULL)
        handleErrors();

    if(1 != EVP_DigestFinal_ex(mdctx, *digest, digest_len))
        handleErrors();

    EVP_MD_CTX_destroy(mdctx);
}
```

Comment: +1 for giving an alternative! I have not so much practice with C code nowadays. I've just corrected the mistakes for fun. :) Maybe your attempt is even better...